# Advice for Web Site Development (WinCE)

Tags: asp-classic, windows-ce, web, isapi

I need to set up a web server on WinCE (7.0) and the following are some of the features that I need to implement through this web site:

- be able to update the device software (run an exe) and display output
- start/end process
- display the run-time of device

Should I use ASP or ISAPI on my web server on WinCE 7(WEC 7) platform? If you include some reasons for your response, it would be great.

I was planning on using ASP because of its simplicity compared to ISAPI; however, when I tested a simple Hello World(hello.asp) page on the device, it took around 30 seconds to load the page. For testing purposes, I am using Windows Virtual PC. So I am not sure what is causing it to be so slow. If you could please enlighten me on this topic too, it would be great.

I looked up ASP .NET Compact framework but I am concerned about performance again.

I am beginner on WinCE development and web development so any answers would be greatly appreciated.

If you need any other information to better answer the question, please let me know and I will provide it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic ASP on CE is really, really limited.  You're not going to be able to hit your targets without a custom COM control, which is not very fun to write or debug and it will have to be installed on the service device.  Out of the two you've proposed, ISAPI is the only one that will reasonably do what you want.

It's a side note, but from experience I'd not use either due to the absolute pain of debugging either one.  I'd use a separate commercial ASP.NET web server for Windows CE.  Of course I created it, so I'm biased, but really, even creating your own port 80 server is going to be less painful than the piss-poor out-of-box offerings in CE.

Answer (score 2):

I found out the problem with the slow loading ASP. It is an error with the WinCE 7 web server. Microsoft has released an update that fixes that problem.

[Windows Embedded Compact 7 Monthly Update July 2011](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2568877)

So I think I will go ahead and use ASP. I'll see if I can add the features that I need to implement.